# Deleting old windows files through ubuntu

Tags: windows, files, delete

I had a pc with windows vista on and then got a new laptop so i installed ubuntu onto the vista pc using the USB installer (i didnt really know what i was doing just messing about i dont know a lot about this stuff however im competent with computers and such, enough knowhow to build a pc). Since then for some reason windows has become corrupted and wont launch so i cant go in to delete the files to clear up space as there is very little space left. Is there a way i can do this through ubuntu?

Edit: Its dual boot as it gives me the option to choose but the vista one doesnt actually work for some reason, system restores and fixes failing.
I cant see any of the files for the vista side from within ubuntu to delete them in the first place.

Comment: Did you dual-boot the vista pc, or replace vista? Sounds like you did a dual-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a new laptop, and since your old laptop won't boot Windows, your best bet is to just reinstall Ubuntu on it(12.04 or 12.10). Use the entire disk and forget about deleting the Windows files from Ubuntu, etc. That's the easiest way forward.

If you really want to delete the Vista files/partition without reinstalling then just use `disk utility` or GParted and reformat the Vista partition. Open either program, select the Vista partition(s), and delete them.

Comment: I would add that, if you don't want to use Windows Vista anymore, use Gparted and delete the whole windows partition, and format it as ext4, it will give you back the space to use in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with Ubuntu, but I have run a dual boot operating system before. It should be possible to view files in the other partition, and unless Vista denies permission, you can probably delete some. I ran a dual boot with two versions of windows (XP and 7 beta) and I could view files, music, and photos, but not programs. Windows Permissions might deny you access to delete the files, but I think that you should be able to view them anyway.
Windows may have become corrupted because the partition was created on a drive containing data already. Usually it is best to only partition on a formatted drive, and then install your operating systems.